# How do I draw line in VIM?

Tags: vim

How do I draw a vertical line instead of typing one by one?

For example, I wanna set a vertical line in column 10 for 20 rows. Just like my first line.
how do I do that in smart way?

[image]

Comment: Try reading about `gr` and `gR` vim modes

Answer (score 15, accepted):

First, set [`virtualedit=all`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/options.html#%27virtualedit%27), to allow yourself to navigate past the end of a line:

```
:set virtualedit=all
```

Then:

```
10|<C-V>20jr|
```

Where:

- [`10|`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/motion.html#bar): moves you to screen column 10
- [<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd>](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/visual.html#blockwise-visual): enters blockwise visual mode "v" typed as a control character; that is, typing "v" while holding the CTRL key down.  The case of "v" does not matter; thus CTRL-V and CTRL-v are equivalent.  But on some terminals, using the SHIFT key will produce another code, don't use it then. [Source: Vim documentation: intro / notation / CTRL-{char}](https://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/intro.html#CTRL-%7Bchar%7D)
- [`20j`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/motion.html#j): moves you down 20 lines (adjust to taste)
- [`r|`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/change.html#simple-change): replaces the selection with bars

Answer (score 2):

The following is an alternative solution to setting `virtualedit=all` in order to make 20 rows with a `|` in column 10:

1. Starting in [Normal](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/intro.html#Normal) mode, make an example line, e.g. `10i<space><esc>r|`

   - `10i`<kbd>space</kbd> will insert <kbd>space</kbd> ten times, and pressing <kbd>esc</kbd> followed by `r|` will replace the last character with a `|`
2. Copy the entire line with `Y`
3. In Normal mode, paste the copied line 20 times with `20p`

   - This will paste the recently copied line 20 times below, giving you a total of 21 identical lines

In sum:

```
10i<space><esc>r|Y20p
```

Answer (score 1):

This appears to be a VIM plugin to do exactly what you are looking for:

http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=40

I have not tried it myself.

Comment: Because initially I posted it with an assinine comment and people got offended...

Comment: +1 for sportsmanship _and_ discipline. Also, of the course the script needed to be mentioned.

Comment: this is actually a nice trolling/score pumping technique: post crap, get downvoted, then fix-replace with a useful answer and watch everyone up vote in suprise.  No way I would have gotten +60 on a stupid response like that. (before downvoting begins -- this was not intentional!  just an observation)

Comment: May I also suggest my own plugin for drawing in vim (I've tried it and it's not bad) https://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=5915